# Microsoft Visio and Sparx Enterprise Architect Compatability

Tags: compatibility, microsoft-visio, enterprise-architect

I am creating UML diagrams using Sparx Enterprise Architect and a colleague of mine is using Microsoft Visio.  Can Visio open EA diagrams, and/or can EA open Visio diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparx Systems have free downloadable solution available from their products page which allows you to import Visio diagrams directly into Enterprise Architect.

Hope this helps!

You can find the download here: [Visio importer for Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/bin/VisioImporter.exe)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  I didn't know that existed.  Now, if I can find a way to use EA diagrams in Visio I'll be set.